# Numpy's npv calculation

Tags: python, numpy, finance

I am computing a NPV with numpy and with my own code, and the results differ. I must be making a mistake somewhere. Any pointer?

```
// Solution 1
r = .06
flows = {0:1200, 3:-450, 6:-450, 15:-450}
print  sum([C/(1+r)**i for i,C in flows.iteritems()])
// => 317

// Solution using numpy's npv function
flows = zeros(16)
flows[0] = 1200
flows[3] = -450
flows[6] = -450
flows[15]= -450
print np.npv(r, flows)
// => 299
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like (despite what it says [in the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.npv.html)) `np.npv` starts summing with t = 1, not t = 0:

```
In [56]: r = 0.06

In [57]: R = r+1

In [58]: (1200/R**0 - 450/R**3 - 450/R**6 - 450/R**15)
Out[58]: 317.16980210661666

In [59]: (1200/R**0 - 450/R**3 - 450/R**6 - 450/R**15)/R
Out[59]: 299.21679444020435

In [64]: np.npv(r, flows)*(1+r)
Out[64]: 317.16980210661683
```

---

Indeed, `np.npv` is [defined this way](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/financial.py#L646):

```
def npv(rate, values):
    values = np.asarray(values)
    return (values / (1+rate)**np.arange(1,len(values)+1)).sum(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in `numpy 1.8`

> Fix to financial.npv
>
> The npv function had a bug. Contrary to what the documentation stated,
>   it summed from indexes 1 to M instead of from 0 to M - 1. The fix
>   changes the returned value. The mirr function called the npv function,
>   but worked around the problem, so that was also fixed and the return
>   value of the mirr function remains unchanged.

[NumPy 1.8.0 Release Notes](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.8.0-notes.rst)

If I use `np.npv` in `numpy 1.8` I get:

```
import numpy as np

r = .06

flows = np.zeros(16)
flows[0] = 1200
flows[3] = -450
flows[6] = -450
flows[15]= -450

result = np.npv(r, flows)
```

Result:

```
>>> result
317.16980210661666
```